# Bindings with key sequences

Tags: tmux, keymapping

Does *Tmux* supports key-bindings with key **sequences** like *Vim* does (e.g. bind-key **ab** kill-pane)? Or how can i emulate that?

Comment: What have you tried? Could you that to the question so that we can help you with specific problems?

Comment: @Petr I tried to hack on evdev, it was too complicated.

Comment: Define "hack" in this context. And like Petr said, can you show us some code that you've tried?

Comment: I stripped down the question to just one unit!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tmux supports only single character key bindings (unfortunately).

So, only this:

```
bind-key a kill-pane
```

or this:

```
bind-key b kill-pane
```

Please note this is different from for example `C-a` (Ctrl-a) or `M-a` (Alt-a).

Even though we users write those with multiple characters and even have to press 2 keys to invoke them, both Ctrl-a and Alt-a are actually a single character for tmux (and in general to my knowledge).

**Alternative**

...might not be what you expect, but here it is:

```
# in .tmux.conf
bind a command-prompt -p "pressed a" "run '~/my_script %%'"
```

And the example `my_script` file:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
  b)
    tmux kill-pane
    ;;
  c)
    tmux kill-window
    ;;
esac
```

Now after you reload your tmux.conf and press `prefix + a` you'll get a tmux prompt saying 'pressed a'.

Go ahead and press `b` and `Enter`. `tmux kill-pane` from the script will execute.

Similarly if you press `prefix + a + c` and `Enter` you'll execute another option from the script.

This kind-of mimics what you want with the addition of `Enter` key at the end.

Also, the provided script is extendable so you can add more "bindings" to get `prefix + a + d + Enter` etc..

Answer (score 12):

I'm using tmux 2.3.

You can emulate key sequences by defining your own key tables and chaining them together.

For example, if I want `<C-q>x` to do something, I put the binding for 'x' into a key table "my-keys", then bind the key that activates that key table with `switch-client` (C-q):

```
bind-key -Tmy-keys x send-keys "my binding"

# Multi-key prefix for custom bindings
bind-key -Troot C-q switch-client -Tmy-keys
```

NOTE: I started with C-q, because it seems to conflict the least with the command line and Vim.

So, now you have every key at your disposal with a C-q prefix.

If you want more keys in your sequence, add another level of indirection:

```
bind-key -Tmy-keys x send-keys "my binding"

# Pane (i.e. 'W'indow commands like Vim with C-w)
bind-key -Tmy-keys-window-ctl s swap-pane
bind-key -Tmy-keys C-w switch-client -T my-keys-window-ctl

# Multi-key prefix for custom bindings
bind-key -Troot C-q switch-client -Tmy-keys
```

So, now I have `swap-pane` bound to `<C-q><C-w>s`.

This works because

1. `<C-q>` activates "my-keys" key table,
2. which has the binding `<C-w>`,
3. which activates "my-keys-window-ctl" key table
4. which has the binding `s` to call `swap-pane`